# AnythingSlider and Cufon bug in IE8 - Low performance and delay

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cufon, anythingslider

I have the following call to AnythingSlider:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#vitrine").anythingSlider({
        buildArrows         : false,
        autoPlayLocked      : true,
        hashTags            : false,
        delay               : 5000,
        resumeDelay         : 5000,
        animationTime       : 500,
        startText           : "",
        stopText            : ""
    });

})
```

And the following call to Cufon:

```
Cufon.replace(".eras", { hover: {color: '#ffae00'} } );
```

In the content of the sliders i have "p" tags that has the class "eras". In Firefox it works perfectly, but in IE8 there is a delay, first the slider is shown, but its number on the navigation bar takes approximatelly 1 second to be updated.

The page URL is www.visamedica.com.br

Looking for help on Google and Groups i didn't find a solution, can anybody help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does [this blog post](http://blog.jmedwards.net/post/1484780565/cufon-delay) fix the problem at all?

Comment: @fudgey, The loading became better with this tip, but the delay between the navigation and the slide continues. Anyway, thanks for your help!